# Deploying Silverlight applications to WinPhone7 emulator without Visual Studio

Tags: deployment, emulation, windows-phone-7

As per title, I would like to deploy my application without its Visual Studio project. I would prefer to place all executables/images/manifests in one directory and deploy it without needing the source or opening Visual Studio.

There is a [way to do that](http://www.j2i.net/BlogEngine/post/2010/04/10/Simulating-an-Accelerometer-in-the-Windows-Phone-7-Emulator.aspx) for XNA apps, but it doesn't work for Silverlight apps for some reason. Other people had [the same problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/023d5f73-0528-47ee-add4-9f57f7d29815).

**EDIT** I know Phone Developer Tools are free and I am not trying to eliminate VS from my workflow. I just want to be able to grab the latest binary from the build server and quickly run it up in demo situations.

Answer (score 2):

When you install the latest developer tools you get an application called "XAP Deployment" which can install a pre-built XAP onto either the emulator or the phone.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out once i install it. Got pulled off WP7 and focusing somewhere else atm...

Answer (score 1):

[How to: Use the XAP Deployment Tool for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769512%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Express is free, and I think you can get a version of VS2010 now too.